# How to make a regular pentagon from technic bricks

Tags: building, technic

For the purposes of this build, we need a pentagon (figure with 5 sides), that is regular (all sides have equal length), and it needs to be able to be mounted on a build (like a wreath) by a technic-friction-pin, (the little black ones).

This may be hard to achieve, with the given possible angles. The pentagonal shape *must* maintain its shape, no warping, etc. It must also be made of "properly fitting pieces."

Comment: Do you allow for the use of non-current technic pieces?

Comment: Absolutely. Old pieces are always fun.

Comment: About what size and thickness are you looking for?

Comment: I'd really like to know this as well. I can think of several ways (will post one as answer) but I'd like something more elegant and compact and can't think of anything better

Answer (score 6):

Using the same length ratios as in the construction that Philo posted in his answer I created this:

[image]
[image]

It uses length 5, 6 and 7 thin liftarms (5 of each) and 30 half-pins
I'm quite happy with it!

Answer (score 5):

A solution, using a (quite precise) approximation:
[image]
Granted, it's a bit bulky, but it could be reduced by half using 7.5 stud long stiffeners (eg. using Technic brick 1+ Technic brick 8 +plates)

Link to LDraw file: http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/Philo/misc2/pentagon/pentagon.ldr

Comment: I see the pentagon outer angle created by triangle with sides 15, 12 and 6 for a 108.21 degree which is indeed a good Approximation, but you could make it a third as small with a  5,4,2 triangle!

Answer (score 2):

Recently came across this problem again, so I'd like to post another answer (2 answers actually).

I figured out how to create an "exact" pentagram (no approximations) using only swivel plates and turntables (blue in the picture):

[image: FB image smaller]

The math very shortly: cos(Pi/5) = (1+sqrt(5))/4 and sqrt(5) can be created with a (2,sqrt(5),3) righthanded triangle.

I posted this in the FB group ["LEGO math and patterns"](https://www.facebook.com/groups/609913687011559), one of the group members mentioned a paper "Mecanno math" by Gerard ’t Hooft which can be found [here](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/meccano.pdf), which has several elegant solutions, e.g. figure 7 in the paper lists 6 solutions:
[image: figure 7 in the paper]

It should be straightforward how the Meccano strips can be replaced by Technic liftarms (as the original poster asked).

Another response I got in another FB group is that this constructions works quite well:
[image]

I tried it and they are correct, the pentagon is rigid and the elements do not seem under undue stress.

[image]

Comment: "figure 7" right above a picture of 6 constructions that are labeled with letters?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use 10 of either one of these: [4273 Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Toggle Joint Toothed](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4273#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)  or [4273a Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Toggle Joint Toothed - Without Slots](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4273a#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), together with 5 equal length axles and 5 pins. Creates a sturdy pentagon. Use the pin connector hole to attach the pentagon to other structures.

[image]

If you don't want axles, but bricks, you can mount connections onto the bricks to mount these 4273s the same way.

Comment: It's impossible to create a pentagon with 10 Axle and Pin Connectors. The reason is simple, each angle of a pentagon must be of 108°. But pin connectors can only have the following angles: 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5 and 180°. So it's impossible to create a pentagon with these connectors.

Comment: You could argue that 112,5 is close enought to 108 degrees. The pentagram is indeed under a bit of stress though, axles are slightly bent

Answer (score 0):

A right triangle with sides 3 by 1 has as largest angle 71.5650512 and smallest 18.4349488 degrees.
That is reasonably close enough to 72 and 18 degrees which can be used to create a pentacle. Lots of right angled connectors or beams you could use then...